# Documentum REST API (dm_audittrail)

Tags: python, rest, documentum, audit-trail, opentext

For user creation ,I am getting the data in attribute_list of dm_audittrail but when I am adding the user in some group then dm_audittrail is not populating with dm_save event .

I am using cara as front end so whenever I am clicking on save button from front end(cara) in edit user window after adding the user in group then dm_audittrail is populating with attribute_list column.So I thought to call the API(http://localhost:8009/dctm-rest/repositories/repo1/users/Vikas Rana) with post method so that I will get the data in attribute_list column but not succeeded.

I am able to  generate the data with  event name as dm_save using above API but attribute_list is not populating.

Please help.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Hi @Miki , I want attribute_list column to be populated when adding the user in a group  from API by using API --> http://localhost:8009/dctm-rest/repositories/repo1/users/Vikas Rana. I want to know what will be the JSON  body to pass in this API using POST Method.

Comment: please, update your post with your question. You can't expect others to spend their time on your problem unless you are willing to spend yours

Answer (score 0):

From your post seems that your system have setup for auditing event for dm_user table. What you want is the audit event triggered on the dm_group table. Try something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Miki, Actually audit trails are creating in dm_group table when adding user into the group but my question is..Is there any way to create the audit entry in dm_user table if we are adding user in the group .?

Comment: Audit trails are creating not in dm_group nor in dm_user table. Audit trails can be found in dm_audittrail table. I believe you are asking me is there a way to generate audit trail for dm_user table in case when user is added to dm_group. I believe it cannot be done with OOTB mechanism since only changes are on the dm_group tables. But don't listen to me and do your own research.

Comment: Hi @Miki , Thanks for the information . One more question :  I am getting the data in  attribute_list column of dm_audittrail for some repositories when creating the user from  API but for some repositories ,I am getting blank data in attribute_list . So  do  you know if there is any configuration change required to populate this column ?

Comment: Of course there is. Audit trails events are repository based, they need to be configured.